# Mean.io project doesn't work

Tags: mean-stack, mean.io

When I did `mean init` and `npm install`, after that in *project* folder I don't have *packages* folder. And when doing `gulp`, I get an error:

> Failed to lookup view "500" in views directory "C:\myApp\views" ;

I don't have *views* folder in *project* folder too.
How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This was originally answered in [gitter](https://gitter.im/linnovate/mean) community by @zeeshanbashir.

First update node version to 6.2.2

> http://tecadmin.net/upgrade-nodejs-via-npm/

1) Clone the 0.6.0 branch, because master branch is missing the 'packages' directory:

```
git clone -b 0.6.0 https://github.com/linnovate/mean.git mean-060
```

2) Initialize mean.io and don't create admin (answer N)

```
mean init myApp
```

3) Copy over the packages directory

```
mean-060/packages myApp
```

4) Run npm with verbose flag

```
cd myApp && npm install --verbose

gulp
```

6) visit localhost:3000